# Collect data with central management servers and keep them in local table

Tags: sql-server

I have 50 servers. I manage them from a central management server.

I could open a query and get result for each one at the same time. But I want to do it in an automated way, like a job, to collect data from each server and store/handle it locally.

Is this possible and if so, how?